# Setting UseWPF to true in a win forms proj file fails to recognize ApplicationConfiguration bootstrap code

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-6.0

In a WinForms desktop application targeting .NET 6, the [UseWindowsForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#usewindowsforms) element in the proj file is set to `True`, and a bootstrap `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();` is generated and called from the startup file `Program`.

Now I want to enable WPF by setting [UseWPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#usewpf) to `True`. When I do that and build I get the following error in the output log

> Program.cs(11,13,11,37): error CS0103: The name 'ApplicationConfiguration' does not exist in the current context.

If I comment out that line the application builds and I can open a WPF window from the a WinForm. But the win form windows look different since they are not properly initialized so I'd like to keep the call to `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();`

Any idea how to set  [UseWPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#usewpf) to `True` and still use `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();`? Thx.

#### To Reproduce

1. Create a new Windows Forms project in VS 2022 targeting .NET 6.
2. Go to proj properties and check the `Enable WPF for this project` check box
3. Add a WPF window to the project
4. Build

You will now get

> Program.cs(11,13,11,37): error CS0103: The name 'ApplicationConfiguration' does not exist in the current context.

in the output log. (The Error List is confused and might not show anything)

##### Proj file

Following the above steps the proj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UseWPF>True</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Possibly show what your project file looks like, it's easier to reproduce (since the sequence modifies the MSBuild pipeline). -- `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize()` is just a template replacement to default calls you can see in any .Net Framework / .Net 5 program.cs file. You can simply replace that single call with the *standard* ones.

Comment: Replacing the call with its content works, but according to (this article)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/windows-forms/6.0/application-bootstrap#reason-for-change] the `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize()` call "Allows the Windows Forms designer to render the design surface in the preferred font".
I have added steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is not such a big deal since I can create a WPF library and use from the Forms proj. But it would be nice if it worked.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/windows-forms/6.0/application-bootstrap#recommended-action

Comment: @HansPassant My issue is enabling WinForms and WPF in the same .NET 6 project . I don't target an earlier version of .NET, which is what post talks about.
There are two checkboxes in the properties UI for a windows desktop project -- Enable WPF for this project, and -- Enable WinForms for this project -- so seems to me it supposed to work to enable them both.

Comment: The link tells you how to *replace* ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize().  Maybe they'll fix the problem some day, encouraged by you using Help > Send Feedback, but for now that's the workaround you'll have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and I did two things:

1. I posted this issue on GitHub issues for WinForms it has been set as a .NET
   7 Milestone Link -> [Github WinForm Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/6947)
2. My workaround code for EnableWPF in Winforms (NET 6) is to edit the Program.CS file to
   below:

Comment the Code Below in Program.CS - (Uncomment in the future and check if .NET Fixes or VS IDE Updates fixed the issue)

```
//ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
```

Then Add the following Code below the comment

```
Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Comment: As commented above: Replacing the call with its content works, but according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/windows-forms/6.0/application-bootstrap#reason-for-change) the ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize() call "Allows the Windows Forms designer to render the design surface in the preferred font". So that doesn't work.
Anyway, thanks for the GitHub post. I'll mark as answer.